# New string to translate in Prestashop 1.6.0.9

Tags: string, translation, prestashop

I need help with Prestashop translations.
I would like to add a few strings to translations in blockcms module. I've added them to .tpl file in this format:
{l s='Awards and certificates' mod='blockcms'}
and I've added to file modules/blockcms/translations/pl.php following line:
$_MODULE['<{blockcms}prestashop>blockcms_0b7b4b09a465b93640bc3f8822ff26eb'] = 'Nagrody i certyfikaty';
where 0b7b4b09a465b93640bc3f8822ff26eb is 'Awards and certificates' in md5.
Unfortunately translation is not showing in BO and string is not replace in store... What is wrong?
I guess I should register new string to translation in blockcms.php file, but I've looked there and it didn't help me to understand how it should be done.
Thank is advance for any replies ;)

Answer (score 0):

To add a translation, you have to translate via backoffice : localisation > translation.
You should not edit translation files